# Ordering On basis of Integer Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I am using this code for ordering , its working fine on case of Name, url etc But I want to order on basis of id  (which is integer field) and I get this error

**function lower(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ws_sources_newssource"."deleted" IS NULL ORDER BY LOWER("new...**

And my code is as fellow

```
class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)

        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if field.startswith('-'):
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc())
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(Lower(field).asc())
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)

        return queryset
```

**then use it in the ListView**

```
class IngredientListAPIView(ListAPIView):
       search_fields = ['name']
       queryset = models.NewsData.objects.all()
filter_backends =(filters.SearchFilter,CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter,)
ordering_fields = ['id','name','url','language__name','count','key_journalists',]
ordering = ('name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is explicit, you cannot use function lower() on an integer. Sqlite does not really have types, so the data came back as string. Postgres does have types and `field` is coming back as an integer. You will need to explicitly cast `field` as `str(field)`

**UPDATE**
If you want to sort by integer then something like:

```
if ordering:
    return queryset.order_by(field)
```

Comment: kindly check now I have updated question , I got issue I just want to use ordering in django on basis of  integer field , how I can ?

Comment: in case of ascending or descending ?

Comment: How you usually do it in Django ```order_by()``` .  ```order_by(field)``` for ascending, ```order_by(-field)``` for descending.

Comment: I am using almost all fields for ordering , can you please update my code so that I can use it for every one ?

Comment: No. One, I don't know what the types of the fields are.  Two, it is not obvious how the filtering is to be done. Three, you already have examples of how to order_by(). You  just need to set up a dict that maps the field names to a sorting/filtering rule(s) and then apply the rules as you walk over the fields list.