# Django try/catch not working and breaking whole programm

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I was working on a django web using sqlite, I changed it to postgres and suddenly this error start to appearing.

```
ProgrammingError at /api/v1/news-source/all
function lower(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ws_sources_newssource"."deleted" IS NULL ORDER BY LOWER("new...
```

and I am unable to catch it. My code is

```
class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)
        insensitive_ordering = getattr(view, 'ordering_case_insensitive_fields', ())

        if ordering:
            new_ordering = []
            for field in ordering:
                if field in insensitive_ordering:
                    if field.startswith('-'):
                       new_ordering.append(Lower(field[1:]).desc())
                    else:
                       try:
                          new_ordering.append(Lower(field).asc())
                       except django.db.Error as e:
                           new_ordering.append((field).asc())
                       except Exception as e:
                          print(e)
                          new_ordering.append(field)
                else:
                    new_ordering.append(field)
            return queryset.order_by(*new_ordering)

        return queryset
```

Comment: I think it's not a django-specific issue though. Can you try manually migrating a database from Sqlite to Postres? An example document will be [this](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/sqlite.html)

Comment: I just changed DB and migrate , didnt use any old data. @crimsonpython24

Comment: How about `try` and `except ProgrammingError`? Although you need to first find out which exactly line(s) are causing this problem and then you apply the exception block. In some cases, the errors won't just go away with simple if-else blocks.

Comment: I cant net get exact error untill I cant go in except , but untill now unable to go into excpet  @crimsonpython24  .   just I should write this except ProgrammingError  ??

Comment: how to use  except ProgrammingError  ? @crimsonpython24

Comment: W3schol has a pretty good demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_try_except2). As I said before, if-else only limits to the logic, it can't really catch errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering On basis of Integer Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039004/ordering-on-basis-of-integer-django-orm)

Comment: The reason for this and the solution has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039004/ordering-on-basis-of-integer-django-orm